# Mysql, how to select only if exist

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with one query. I would like to select id, option and value from options table but only if options.id exists in products.*. Something like this:

```
SELECT id, option, value 
FROM options 
WHERE EXISTS (
             SELECT * FROM products 
             WHERE products.category="watches" AND products.*=options.id
             );
```

This query returns empty result. I don't know if I'm doing it write, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does it mean "options.id exists in products.*."?

Comment: if options id 10 exists in products.brand, products.type, products.function... I'm storing options id to some of the products columns so I can select only options that exists in products table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think you should have a column in the product table that refers to the options record :

```
SELECT id, option, value FROM options 
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT option_id FROM products WHERE products.category="watches" AND products.option_id=options.id);
```

Comment: "SELECT 1" instead of "SELECT option_id" in your sub-query should also work.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.

```
SELECT IF( EXISTS(
             SELECT * FROM products WHERE products.category="watches" AND products.id=options.id), 1, 0);
```

Comment: my products.id is not linked to options.id

Comment: I just showed it as a representation for your `products.*`. Don't take that as granted. Modify the query as per your needs.